# Which probability distribution fits my data?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, fitting

I have generated a dataset (available [here](https://paste.ee/r/aF404)) for which I try to find out the best fitting probability distribution.

I first generated uniformly distributed random directions and then calculated the angle between two succeeding directions. The dataset are these angles. You can interpret the random directions as random points sampled on the surface of the unit sphere.

The dataset of random directions is available here: [random_dirs.txt](https://paste.ee/r/Ci8PT)

I generated the random directions through polar coordinates $\theta = 2*\pi*u$, $\phi=acos(2v-1)$ (where  $u,v$ are uniformly distributed from (0,1)); this method is also listed on [this site](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html).

I then generate normalized direction vectors $\overrightarrow{n_i}=\left(\begin{array}{c}
\sin(\phi)cos(\theta)\\
\sin(\phi)\\ 
\cos(\phi)) 
\end{array}
\right)$

The angle between two suceeding directions is then calculated using

```
random_dirs = load('random_dirs.txt'); 
rand_dirs_1 = random_dirs(1:end-1,:);
rand_dirs_2= random_dirs(2:end,:);
angles = acos(dot(rand_dirs_1, rand_dirs_2,2));
```

I tried the normal distribution:

**Density (PDF)**
[image: pdf]

**Cumulative Probability (CDF)**

[image]

The CDF matches pretty good, but the PDF could be fitting "better".

Is the data distributed according the normal distribution? How do I verify that? or is there a better matching distribution?

The reason I need to identify a distribution is that I want to compare with other datasets using mean and standard deviation, so I guess first finding out a matching distribution which calculates these measures is necessary.

e.g. this is the same original data, but I applied a spatial sorting algorithm to the random directions and then calculated the angles between neighbouring directions. The angles between the sorted directions are available [here](https://paste.ee/r/cIve3).
The sorting uses a space-filling curve (e.g. Hilbert curve) to map the 3D data into 1D space and sort the directions accordingly.

[image]

[image]

Now I want to compare how much "improvement" in terms of mean and sigma the sorting introduced.

Or are there other measures I could use to express the "improvement"?

---

How many bins should I use for fitting the data? I used `61` according to "Scott's method" (Scott, David W. (1979). "On optimal and data-based histograms".).

According to "Sturges' method" (Sturges, H. A. (1926). "The choice of a class interval") I should use `18` bins which changes the appearance of the data quite a bit, it looks more like a normal distribution:

[image: normal fit with 18 bins]

Comment: Why do you need to identify a distribution?

Comment: How did you generate it?

Comment: @mark999 I updated my question with a description of the generation

Comment: @Glen_b I want to compare other datasets using mean and standard deviation, so I guess first finding out a matching distribution which calculates these measures is necessary

Comment: @Glen_b I added a description how the angles are calculated and a dataset which I want to compare against. I hope this clears things up.

Comment: It would seem that your distribution has thicker tails than a normal distribution so perhaps try a t-distribution at varying degrees of freedom and asess its fit.

Comment: @JohnK I am using MATLAB, but I am unsure which t-distribution you are referring to. Is this the right one? http://mathworks.com/help/stats/t-location-scale-distribution.html

Comment: Yes. Give that a try.

Comment: @JohnK I tried it, but it does not look that much better (see my edit)

Comment: @Johnk those tails are thinner than normal, not thicker. A t-distribution is worse than a normal.

Comment: Please clarify exactly how you calculated the angle; when I calculate the distribution of the angle between two successive uniforms I don't get this, which suggests that there's something unexplained here.

Comment: The distribution of gaps between ordered uniform observations is a problem that has been studied; there are posts here about it; however, there are still things about your circumstances that you need to clarify. If you're just trying to calculate how much improvement there has been, why would you need to identify the distribution?

Comment: @Glen_b Am I missing something? The t-distribution is famous for having thicker tails than the normal.

Comment: @John The empirical distribution of the *data* is thinner tailed than normal. As a result, the heavier-tailed t-distribution is worse.

Comment: @Glen_b yes, you can interpret the random directions as random points sampled on the surface of the unit sphere; I don't necessarily need to express the improvement introduced through the sorting using a probability distribution, I just thought it would a useful measure here. Do you have any other measure I could use?

Comment: If you're interested in improvement in mean and standard deviation (as you say in the question) ... you could just directly measure the change in mean and in standard deviation.

Comment: @Glen_b this might just be the simplest solution, I did not think about this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: It now looks like these are random directions on the *sphere*, in which case the pdf of the distance between random vectors should be $\frac12\sin(\theta);\quad 0<\theta<\pi$. The remainder of this answer is not relevant in that case; I'll probably delete some of it eventually.

I'll need to come back to look at the ordered case to see if I can get anywhere with that.

---

Looking at your data, I'm a little concerned by some lack-of-fit in your data to the theoretical density:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Given your large sample size, this suggests you may not actually be getting quite a random distribution for some reason. There's slightly too many angles around $\pi/2$ and slightly too few in the region around $\pi/3$ and $2\pi/3$

While the deviation is small, it's large enough to lead to rejection by a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test ($p$ about $1.35\times 10^{-5}$). I'm not sure why that's happening but your simulated s.d. will be slightly too small as well.

---

(my old answer)

> Is the data distributed according the normal distribution?

Your data are not drawn from a normal distribution.

> How do I verify that?

You can't. You can sometimes rule it out, as here, but you can't conclude that the data *were* drawn from a normal distribution on the basis of the appearance of the data.

> or is there a better matching distribution?

Oh, an infinite number of them. If you would seek a simple model for data like that, a scaled (i.e. to be on $(0,\pi)$) beta distribution might be adequate, but if you know something about what the values consist of it's likely you can come up with better options.

> I try to find out the best fitting probability distribution.

"Best" depends on your criteria. What are we to try to do best at? (e.g. what are you using this to do?)

Comment: I think it more like a beta distribution

Comment: how do you know the PDF of the random directions is $\frac12\sin(\theta);\quad 0<\theta<\pi$? can you point me to any source please? I did not think of a sine/cosine distribution, but now that you mention it: should I go with the [Raised cosine distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raised_cosine_distribution)?

Comment: It's pretty straightforward. It follows immediately from the distribution of polar angles [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html) (you can just call one of the vectors the pole); there's also a derivation [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1246748/distribution-of-an-angle-between-a-random-and-fixed-unit-length-n-vectors) for example.

Comment: thanks for the links, they really cleared things up. which additional explanation do you need? I will gladly update my question with that necessary information. The sorting uses a space-filling curve (e.g. Hilbert curve) to map the 3D data into 1D space and sort the directions accordingly.

Comment: I added this detail also to my question; what do you mean by "simulate the other one"?

Comment: Just what you already have done (but if you need additional accuracy, replicated as many more times as you need).

Comment: @Glen_b regarding your edit about the lack-of-fit: the random directions are generated through the polar coordinates $\theta = 2*\pi*u$, $\phi=acos(2v-1)$ (where  $u,v$ are uniformly distributed from (0,1)); this method is also listed on the [page you linked to](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html). (I added this detail to the question as well); do you see any problem with my method?

Comment: I hadn't noticed it there at the link, but I derived it myself before I posted that update; when I generated my own values that way, I got a very close match to the sin distribution. Is it possible your original random directions in the file aren't quite random? Incidentally, look at the cos of your original data. If those data are angles between random 3-vectors, that $\cos(\theta)$ should look uniform, but it's not.

Comment: I generated another dataset (available [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=57533877486997760908)) and it fits the theoretical pdf better: http://i.imgur.com/O0gwoj7.png; I don't know if I executed the kstest correctly, it reports `p = 0.0124`; can you please give an example how you generated your data and executed the test? it does not have to be in MATLAB, I'd just like to see how it's done

Comment: I went by the $\text{acos}(2v-1)$ approach. That's already directly from the sin distribution as long as you have uniforms, since it's actually the inverse cdf method for generating the sin distribution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27070/discussion-between-m-s-and-glen-b).

Answer (score 0):

For a one-dimensional distribution of angles, you might look into the von Mises distribution. One thing the von Mises distribution does is account for the equivalence between the endpoints of your domain, e.g. an angle of 0 is the same as an angle of $2\pi$.

There are other 1-dimensional distributions that have this quality - for example you could "wrap" the density of pretty much any continuous distribution onto the range 0 to $2\pi$ - see "wrapped Normal distribution", or wrapped t, or wrapped Cauchy.

Comment: Being angles between 3D vectors, these angles are on the half-circle.